# Interpreting conditional probability fallacy, probability of having a girl

Tags: conditional-probability

Given the great answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1801261/984376 I do understand

1. P(second child =girl|First child = girl) =0.5 and
2. P(both girls|at least one girl)=1/3.

Let's say for a given part of the population I knew that the first child is a girl and let's say that we could bet x dollar on the next child being a boy, the payout should be 2x.

Would people

A) win on average some money if they would bet that for this population the second child is a boy (due to P(both girls|at least one girl)=1/3<0.5) OR

B) would a bet not make any sense due to P(second child =girl|First child = girl) =0.5?

Additional question C) Under which scenario could I make money by making use of P(both girls|at least one girl)=1/3<0.5?

Comment: The answer depends on what the "given part of the population" might be.  How exactly might it be selected?

Comment: I would assume that I look at a random sample of the population and from that sample I only look at the families where the first child is a girl (in a "rejection sampling way").

Comment: Okay.  But then you appear to be re-asking the original question (1), merely recasting the probability of $1/2$ in the form of a bet paying $2:1.$  It's as if you are telling us you understand the answer but you don't believe it!

Comment: I see where you are heading with your initial remark: although the event "first child is a girl" implies the event "at least one girl", the **reverse direction is not true**! Therefore, the answer B) is correct: if I know the first child is a girl, then it is 50-50 of finding a boy or a girl as the second child. This is great. This also answers Point C) you can make money with a bet if the pairs of children are sampled such that at least one girl is present and then you have a 2/3 chance of finding a boy. Do you want to make this an answer? I will accept it then.